# AEM adaptive image showing images over port 80 on localhost but not externally with apache

Tags: apache, aem, adaptive-design

I'm serving my AEM site with Apache over port 80 and I'm noticing that when I use localhost:80/content/mproject/en/index.html my adaptive image component displays images but when I go to www.myproject.com:80/content/mproject/en/index.html the adaptive image component is not showing anything.

I'm sure this must be an Apache error because when I use IIS to serve AEM, the adaptive image component works as expected from an external address. I'm also sure it's not the rewrite rules because the image does not show externally whether I have the rewrite rules present or if I delete them and restart my webserver.

I can post my httpd.conf file if that will help, but at them moment it looks like I might be overlooking something silly as Apache is showing all images normally from an external address except those from the adaptive image component. Also, IIS displays the adaptive image from an external address properly with a default configuration. Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: 1. using dispatcher? 2. what is the actual path to the adaptive image?

Comment: I am using the dispatcher. The actual path is "/content/myproject/en/index/services/jcr:content/page-content-responsive/r1col100/custom_adaptiveimage.img.full.high.jpeg" Other requests to that path are being served as far as I can tell because the other images on the page have a similar path but are not adaptive.

Comment: I've got some more information to add that might help. I've noticed that when I turn off caching on the dispatcher, the images are served correctly. The images are trying to cache to /jcr:content/ and the dispatcher is refusing to cache it because it doesn't resolve to a readable directory structure. The requests for other images get the /jcr:content/ portion of their request rewritten to /_jcr_content/ which is cacheable. I might be able to turn off caching for the adaptive image via the dispatcher, but that's hardly a satisfactory solution.

Comment: That is to say, in dispatcher.any, if I set /rules { /0000 { /glob "*" /type "deny" } then it starts to load the images correctly, but it isn't caching anything then so that doesn't exactly solve the problem.

Comment: I fixed the problem by I adding this rewrite rule RewriteRule (.+)/(.+?):(.+?)/(.+) $1/_$2_$3/$4 [R=302,L] after finding a description of the problem and resolution here: http://sxopi1.blogspot.ca/2014/08/aem-and-apache-22-publish-dispatcher-on.html